# SSRS Column Grouping Not working as desired

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016

I'm unable to get grouping correct to properly output as required in a report. I have included a condensed mono-spaced example demonstrating the query results, desired report output, and closest actual output achieved.

**Query Resuts**

```
Person Sales   Quarter
Jim    $10.00  2015Q1
Jim    $20.00  2015Q2
Jim    $30.00  2015Q3
Jim    $40.00  2015Q4
John   $50.00  2015Q1
John   $60.00  2015Q2
John   $70.00  2015Q3
John   $80.00  2015Q4
```

**Desired Report**

```
Person 2015Q1 2015Q2 2015Q3 2015Q4
Jim    $10.00 $20.00 $30.00 $40.00
John   $50.00 $60.00 $70.00 $80.00
```

**Closest Actual Report**

```
       2015Q1 2015Q2 2015Q3 2015Q4
Person Sales  Sales  Sales  Sales 
       $10.00                     
              $20.00              
Jim                  $30.00       
                            $40.00
       $50.00                     
              $60.00              
John                 $70.00       
                            $80.00
```

I Row grouped on Person. Sales is in detail section and I parent column grouped on detail section by Quarter.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Insert matrix, then drag `Person` to `Rows`, drag `Quarter` to `Columns`, then drag `Sales` to `Data`. That should be it. The groups should be added correctly when you do this.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks! I wasn't using matrix. That did the trick! Feel free to post as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: done, glad you got it sorted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert matrix, then drag Person to Rows, drag Quarter to Columns, then drag Sales to Data. That should be it. The groups should be added correctly when you do this.